# Where do I call '.to_i' in this code?

Tags: ruby, string, methods

I'm going through Chris Pine's *Learn to Program*, and I couldn't get this exercise to work.
The gets a `num` from the user, and then is supposed to tell the user that `num + 1` Is a bigger and better number.

With this code:

`1  puts 'What\'s your favorite number?'
2  num = gets.chomp
3  num = num.to_i + 1
4  puts num +' is a bigger and better favorite number.'`

I get this error for line 4:

`in '+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)`

So my string variable isn't actually getting converted to an integer, right? How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line, the code is trying to concatenate a number with a string.

```
>> 1 + ' is ...'
TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
        from (irb):2:in `+'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Convert a number to string before concatenation. And there should be space between `+` and '...'

```
puts num.to_s + ' is a bigger and better favorite number.'
               ^
```

---

Or using string interpolation:

```
puts "#{num} is a bigger and better favorite number."
```

Comment: thanks again! Stack Overflow has been so helpful, but I'm obviously still learning the ropes. :)

Answer (score -1):

use this as the last line -

```
puts "#{num} is a bigger and better favorite number."
```